# Total available memory for memory management logic

Tags: android

I am having a problem releasing memory. I have a `Hashmap` in which I am adding a `Bitmap` , and the number of bitmaps is quite large. For this reason, I am getting `OutOfMemoryError`. So for this I have decided to release `Bitmap` which is least used from `Collection`, on memory crunch or system getting low on heap memory.

For getting the current memory available, I used "**ActivityManager.MemoryInfo.availMem**", but it gives the total RAM size memory, not available heap memory. And I found that this **memory is not getting updated on releasing** Bitmap from the collection.

Then I have used these three methods:

```
Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()
Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize()
Debug.getNativeHeapSize()
```

but I found the NativeHeapSize goes on increasing up to some certain level, say 16 MB, changing after that an `OutOfMemoryError` occur. In this also, I found that the `NativeHeapAllocatedSize` and `getNativeHeapSize` is not decreasing on releasing `Bitmap` from `Collection`.

How do I solve this problem?

My problem is I want to calculate the maximum available application memory allocated and currently available memory, such that if the currently available memory goes beyond the threshold memory I will release some `Bitmap` from the collection and [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) will reclaim the memory and free it without generating an error.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Storing `Bitmaps` in memory is VERY expensive.  Depending on the image format each pixel can consume up to 4 bytes of memory.

Are you displaying the entire `Collection` of `Bitmaps` at the same time? If not I would highly suggest that store **NOT** store the undisplayed `Bitmaps` but rather store a `URI` for the image and load it on the fly when you need it.

If you are displaying the entire collection I would make sure you are downsampling the bitmaps to the appropriate size such that you aren't storing pixels that aren't getting rendered.

Comment: Yes i am frequently using these bitmaps but not all, its total on user usage if he continually traversing in the app then used mostly bitmaps, and these bitmap are loaded from server, and if i release these bitmap user will have to wait for loading these images again. So is there any other way, or am i going in wrong way please help me.

Comment: You should definitely save the images to a local file so you only load them from the server once.  Loading and displaying an image from a local file can be very fast!

Comment: Yes i do with your suggestion, but cant we have the ActualMemoryAvailable and TotalMemoryAvailabe in the App?